# How do I do func( of datarow)

Tags: vb.net, linq

This should be easy but I'm not getting it. After an hour of Googling and MSDN perusing I'm still not getting it.

I want to sum an entire column in a typed datatable using Linq.

Won't compile:

```
Dim sum4 As Decimal = PmtList.Sum(x  System.Func(Of GSRDataSet.PmtHistRow)())
```

Won't compile:

```
Dim x As Decimal
Dim sum3 = PmtList.AsEnumerable().Sum(x >= x.Field < Int() > ("Balance"))
```

Also tried: Got error "missing operand"

```
Dim sumObj As Object = PmtList.Compute("Sum(Total)", "=<>0")
```

How do I sum an entire column in a datatable using Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *Balance* field is of type *Decimal* then you could do it like this:

```
Dim sum As Decimal = PmtList.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(row As DataRow) row.Field(Of Decimal)("Balance"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Dim sum3 = PmtList.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Int)("Balance"))
```